# Adding block on Product detail page causing problem for notification appearance (product successful added notification)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.7

I have added a block

```
<block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form"></block>
```

Now after adding its working fine but  now after adding product its not showing  green notification which let me know product added successfully.

full code of  `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>

        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="highlight.tab" template="Pakgentors_Jblashes::product/highlight_tab.phtml" after="product_cms_block2" group="detailed_info" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Highlights</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="how_to_use.tab" template="Pakgentors_Jblashes::product/how_to_use.phtml" after="highlight.tab" group="detailed_info" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">How to Use</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>

        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom_size_attr.tab" template="Pakgentors_Jblashes::product/prod_size_option.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
<!-- 
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.description">
            <action method="setTitle">
                <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">How to Use</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock> -->

        <referenceContainer name="product.info.stock.sku" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="view.addto.compare" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.mailto" remove="true" />

        <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true" />
        <move element="product.info.price" destination="page.main.title" />
        <move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" before="-" />

        <!-- product.info.main,product.info.review,product.info.overview,product.info.price,product.price.final -->

        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="product.info.jbreviews" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product info detailed" after="-">
                <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
                    <container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Review Form Fields Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="rewards"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_additional_data" template="product/view/list.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_review_list.toolbar"></block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>

    </body>

</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

From your question it's unclear what you actually did.
But if you really just added this code somewhere you should note that a block with the name `product.review.form` already exists and thus you probably broke Magento templating at some point resulting in your missing notification.

Comment: can you check code again please  ?I updated

Comment: is this the xml of your theme? do you try to move the review form to another element?
please add a reason for adding the block to your question to make it more clear.